# Get android manifest <application> debuggable property value

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Check if android debuggable property is true or not in manifest.

`<application android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="true" >`

How to get debuggable property value programmatically?

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. your answer is correct.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if DEBUGGABLE is true or false using this

```
(getContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0
```

Comment: Tested this thing by decompiling app and manually change manifest(~Add debuggable line) and then rebuild apk, Still I am able to check whether app is debuggable or not.

Answer (score 0):

this.getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0